# Ingress-nginx controller kubernetes global SSL redirections

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx, ssl

I'm struggling to set a global (on ingress controller scope) SSL/HTTPS redirection. It works fine with annotation to specific ingress object, yet wont work globally.

Configmap:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
  proxy-real-ip-cidr: XXX
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  proxy-body-size: "0"
  force-ssl-redirect: "true"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.6.4
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
```

service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "1800"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: XXX
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name: XXX
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: ssl
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.6.4
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: tohttps
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

deployment part:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.6.4
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --election-id=ingress-nginx-leader
        - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --validating-webhook=:8443
        - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
        - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
```

I am able to run:

```
$ curl http://something_in_my_cluister.com

$ curl https://something_in_my_cluster.com
```

and both requests are just fine, one connecting to port `80` and other to `443` while I would like to redirect from `80` to `443`

Answer (score 1):

I did it before using snippets (`values-prod.yaml` example for Helm):

```
controller:
  containerPort:
    http: 80
    https: 80
    redir-to-https: 2443
  config:
    http-snippet: |
      server {
        listen 2443 proxy_protocol;
        return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
    use-proxy-protocol: "true"
    real-ip-header: "proxy_protocol"
    use-forwarded-headers: "true"
    error-log-level: "error"
  replicaCount: 2
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name: "eks-ingress"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "external"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: "ip"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-group-attributes: preserve_client_ip.enabled=false
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "3600"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "false"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: ${ssl_cert_arn}
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06
    externalTrafficPolicy: "Local"
    targetPorts:
      http: redir-to-https
      https: http
  admissionWebhooks:
    enabled: false
```

Here is the same as plain manifests:

Configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.8.2
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.7.2
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: 'true'
  error-log-level: error
  http-snippet: |
    server {
      listen 2443 proxy_protocol;
      return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  real-ip-header: proxy_protocol
  use-forwarded-headers: 'true'
  use-proxy-protocol: 'true'
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  uid: 04ec13ee-9c47-4a5c-949a-c658ad338db4
  resourceVersion: '116095705'
  creationTimestamp: '2023-01-30T05:47:48Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.8.2
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.7.2
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '3600'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'false'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name: eks-ingress
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: '*'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: >-
      arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:000000000000:certificate/c41e22886,
      arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:000000000000:certificate/42799b95a4,
      arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:000000000000:certificate/11d3d05
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-group-attributes: preserve_client_ip.enabled=false
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
  finalizers:
    - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
    - service.k8s.aws/resources
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: redir-to-https
      nodePort: 30722
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: http
      nodePort: 30483
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  clusterIP: 10.100.200.30
  clusterIPs:
    - 10.100.200.30
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  healthCheckNodePort: 31098
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.8.2
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.7.2
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '2'
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.8.2
        helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.7.2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: >-
            registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.8.2@sha256:74834d3d25b336b62cabeb8bf7f1d788706e2cf1cfd64022de4137ade8881ff2
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - '--publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller'
            - '--election-id=ingress-nginx-leader'
            - '--controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx'
            - '--ingress-class=nginx'
            - '--configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller'
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: redir-to-https
              containerPort: 2443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: metrics
              containerPort: 10254
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
              drop:
                - ALL
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      serviceAccount: ingress-nginx
      securityContext: {}
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 100
              preference:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: Environment
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - service
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - ingress-nginx
                  - key: app.kubernetes.io/instance
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - ingress-nginx
                  - key: app.kubernetes.io/component
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - controller
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
```

Comment: Can you share a wider yaml context for this?

Comment: It's the `values-prod.yaml` file I using to install ingress-nginx controller with helm. Are you configuring it via plain manifests?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I am. Based on:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.6.4/deploy/static/provider/aws/nlb-with-tls-termination/deploy.yaml

Comment: Updated answer, hope it helps